# iOS - Caching remote image

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to cache images from the web to prevent excessive web requests to save battery and data. The basic idea is:

1. Generate the string of the File's Location
2. If the file exists then load it from the file
3. If its not in existence (todo: or if the file is older than a day) then download the image from the web. Save it and load it.

However my code isn't working and I can't figure out why?

```
// imagesFileName has been correctly generated as as imageURL
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagesLibraryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];
NSString *imagePath = [imagesLibraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFileName];


// Do We Have the icon in cache?
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:iconPath]) {
    // File Doesn't Exist - Load Image From URL
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagesURL]];

    // Save Image
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];


    NSLog(@"Downloading & Importing Image");
    return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
} else {
    // Load the Image From The File But Update If Needed
    NSLog(@"Loading Image From Cache");
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}
```

Comment: On which case you have a trouble? from reading cache, or writing cache?

Comment: Your `if` statement checks if `iconPath` exists, but I think you mean `imagePath`? Your `NSData` call then creates a URL from `imagesURL`, which I think again should be `imagePath`. Also, if you're caching data, you should place it in the `Library/Caches` folder (`NSCachesDirectory`) so that the OS can delete this data when space is low, as it can be re-downloaded by your app. Placing it in the Caches folder also ensures that it won't automatically be backed up by iTunes and iCloud.

Comment: @ev0lution I've change the iconPath To imagePath, that was just a typo. imageURL refers to the URL on the web to grab the image from, whilst imagePath refers to the saved (cached) files location. How do I get my app's cache directory?

Comment: @dgee4 Use `NSCachesDirectory` instead of `NSDocumentDirectory` to find the Caches directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems here, but firstly, you have not said in what way your code isn’t working. Perhaps we can help more if you provide more information.

I would not recommend using `NSData`’s `dataWithContentsOfURL:`. This method loads data synchronously (code execution in the current function stops until it finishes). This method should typically only be used for local files (with the `file://` URL scheme), not for remote URLs. Look into loading the data asynchronously with [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html) or [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html), and read Apple’s [*URL Loading System Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).

The URL loading system has built-in support for caching, so you should use that if possible and abandon this code entirely. Read [*Understanding Cache Access*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001843-BAJEAIEE) in the *URL Loading System Programming Guide* and also the [*NSURLCache* article on *HSHipster*](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/).

If you do want to write your own caching system (which I do not recommended) then at least:

- Use the Caches directory instead of the Documents directory (see ev0lution’s comment).
- Avoid `NSFileManager`’s `fileExistsAtPath:` (see [the note in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath:)). Instead try loading the image from disk and see if that fails (returns `nil`).

Comment: Can I use the Cacheing for iOS? The links forward me to the mac OS X developer site? Could you give an example about how to create such a cache and retrieve and download data?

Comment: The URL loading system is nearly identical on iOS and OS X. I changed the links to the iOS documentation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In the else part you are just returning image location path. Here you need to pass image name with that path.

So your `else` part should be like this

```
else {
        // Load the Image From The File But Update If Needed
        NSLog(@"Loading Image From Cache");
        // e.g Some image name
        NSString *imageName = @"Image1.png";
        [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    }
```